# Eliminate Select from code and format cells effectively

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to insert a few columns into my worksheet and format the cells as date, time, etc. How can I modify this to remove select from the code? This will be a great learning tool for me (and other users).

```
 Sub ExSD_InsertColumns()
'
' ExSD_InsertColumns Macro
'

'
    Sheets("ExSDReport").Select
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("G:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ARC"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unit Type"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Work Pool ABBR"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time"
    Range("G2").Select
End Sub

Sub ExSD_Date_Time_FormatSet()
'
' ExSD_Date_Time_FormatSet Macro
'

'
    Range("G2:G250").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("H2:H250").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
    Range("J2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select just positions the curser with the next action being that cursor. So you can delete the select statement and then move the `ActiveCell.whatever`. The only exception is using the proper sheet, which instead of selecting, I just referenced with a `with` statement. Make sure to `End When` as shown below.

```vb
Sub ExSD_InsertColumns()
' ExSD_InsertColumns Macro
'
    With Sheets("ExSDReport")
        
        .Columns("B:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Columns("G:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "ARC"
        .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Unit Type"
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Work Pool ABBR"
        .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
        .Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time"
    End With
End Sub
```

[Good one-stop shop on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)